# Engagement Split - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a Journey [SFCRM object as entry source] that has a number of emails that we are sending to contacts. Our requirement is every email has a new link so, whenever someone clicks on that link they should exit the Journey.

How can I achieve this?? If I am using Engagement Split, then we are bound with the time before that.. any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a flag on the contact data that updates when they click... then you can use a decision split mid journey.